# How to access object attribute via django variable?

Tags: python, django

I want to convert this code to something more inheritable to avoid coding. Consider that my code is simple and simple answer is need.

```
{{ entity.name }}
{{ entity.description }}
```

I want to convert to such code:

```
{% for attribute in attributes %}
{{ entity ??? }} == entity.get_attr(attribute)
{% end for %}
```

What is valid syntax for it?

Comment: You'll need to write a customm template tag/filter.

Comment: https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/411/

Answer (score 2):

The easiest example with filter:

```
# templatetags.ry
from django import template


register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def get_attr(object, name):
    return getattr(object, name, '')
```

Your template:

```
{% load templatetags %}


{% for attribute in attributes %}
    {{ entity|get_attr:attribute }}
{% end for %}
```

Comment: Is not possible to do entity[name]?

Comment: It's possible if you use [jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#variables). But in *jinga1* you have to use custom filter.